# Add two lists of different lengths in python, start from the right

Tags: python, coding-style

I want to add two list of different length start from the right
Here's an example

```
[3, 0, 2, 1]
[8, 7]
```

Expected result:

```
[3, 0, 10, 8]
```

These list represent coefficient of polynomials

Here is my implementation

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coeffs = coefficients

    def coeff(self, i):
        return self.coeffs[-(i+1)]

    def add(self, other):
        p1 = len(self.coeffs)
        p2 = len(other.coeffs)
        diff = abs(p1 - p2)
        if p1 > p2:
            newV = [sum(i) for i in zip(self.coeffs, [0]*diff+other.coeffs)]
        else:
            newV = [sum(i) for i in zip([0]*diff+self.coeffs, other.coeffs)]                  
        return Polynomial(newV)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.add(other).coeffs
```

This one work fine, just want to know anyway to do better, cleaner code?
As python always stressed at clean code, I want to know is there any way to write cleaner, pythonic code?

Comment: @Haidro: I don't think so. I have tried to clarify the example. Timothy, if that clarification is wrong, please correct it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I see, but isn't 7+1 9? Or is it 8+1 but then 7+2 != 10

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit (2020-18-03):

```
>>> P = [3, 0, 2, 1]
>>> Q = [8, 7]
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip_longest(reversed(P), reversed(Q), fillvalue=0)][::-1]
[3, 0, 10, 8]
```

Obviously, if you choose a convention where the coefficients are ordered the opposite way, you can just use

```
P = [1, 2, 0, 3]
Q = [7, 8]
[x+y for x,y in zip_longest(P, Q, fillvalue=0)]
```

Comment: I have to say that for consistency it would be nicer to user reversed for the last reversion, instead of [::-1].

Comment: @LennartRegebro, I agree, but that would return a `listreverseiterator` :(

Comment: Well, it's true that maybe he would slice it afterwards.

Comment: @TimothyLeung, if you are using Python3, it's just `zip_longest`

Answer (score 2):

I believe a simple for loop is far simpler than a comprehension with zip_longest...

```
P = [3, 0, 2, 1]
Q = [8, 7]

A, B = sorted([P, Q], key=len)

for i, x in enumerate(reversed(A), 1):
   B[-i] += x

#print(B)
```

If you need to keep `P` unchanged, copy it first. Also, if `Q` is much smaller than `P`, this will be more effective.

Comment: @gnibbler I added the check... Also, this will iterate just the size of the smallest one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L1 = [3, 0, 2, 1]
>>> L2 = [8, 7]
>>> L2 = [0 for i in range(len(L1)-len(L2))] + L2
>>> A1 = np.array(L1)
>>> A2 = np.array(L2)
>>> A1+A2
array([ 3,  0, 10,  8])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0, 1, 3, 4]

b = [5, 6]

iter_len = len(a)-(len(b) - 1)

for j in range(len(a), 0, -1):

        if j-iter_len < 0:
            break
        else:
            a[j-1] = a[j-1] + b[j-iter_len]
print a
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,7,9]

b = [1,2,5]

n = a

addStart = len(a) - len(b)

count = 0

for i in b :

    n[addStart+count] = i + a[addStart+count]
    count+=1
print n
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.